# React Native Redux: this.setState is not changing state

Tags: react-native, redux, native, setstate

this.setState({device}) is not updating the state at all, unless I force it with "this.state.device = __" however it would still be a problem as the component does not re-render. I tried using a callback function such as:

```
this.setState({device: selectedDeviceId}, () => {
    console.log(this.state.device)
})
```

but the code does not log at all, which indicates that setState is not even being called.

```
class Stats extends React.Component {
  state = {
    viewType: 'day',
    dt: moment(),
    device: {}
  }
  getDevice = () => {
    const devices = this.props.devices || []
    const selectedDeviceId = this.props.selectedDeviceId

    devices.forEach((d) => {
      if (d._id === selectedDeviceId) this.setState({device: d})
    })
    if (!this.state.device._id && devices.length) {
      this.setState({device: devices[0]})
    }
    this.getUsage()
  }

  componentWillMount () {
      console.log('Enter StatsScreen.componentWillMount')
      let dt = this.state.dt
      const date = moment(dt).format('YYYY-MM-D')
      console.log(date)
      this.getDevice()
  }
}
```

Comment: can you share the console.log. And the value of "!this.state.device._id && devices.length" to make sure the if statement evaluates to true.

Comment: It will give more idea if you can insert your render function as well

Comment: why is your "componentDidMount" outside of you Stats class?

Comment: Sorry typo in the question. ComponentWillMount is inside the Stats class

Comment: console.log(d) = 
Object
__immutable_invariants_hold:true
_id:"5a1654b2fc92299a7f00001c"
alert_disabled:false
alert_duration:1
alert_interval:60
alert_volume:1... etc

Comment: value of this.state.device._id is null and devices.length is 3 - that is because i did not successfully set state of device, it is still the default empty object

Comment: @Lalaluye Try setting initial state in class constructor

Comment: Setting initial state in class constructor gives same result. Device is undefined.  
constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      viewType: 'day',
      dt: moment(),
      device: {}
    }
  }

Comment: Documention suggest using componentDidMount unless you are performing a server side rendering. Can that be the reason? https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentwillmount

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you're not using React Native state you're using a variable you've made called state. Fix this by writing the constructor lifecycle method and putting this.state = in there to initialise.

Btw avoid doing things like this in the willMount lifecycle method do it in the didMount then you're not blocking the UI.

Comment: I tried this without any luck

constructor (props)
{ super(props) this.state = { viewType: 'day', dt: moment(), device: {} } }

Comment: setting state in didMount fixed this. Thank you!